# RKhunter possible false positive

Tags: rkhunter

Is `/usr/bin/size` being infected a false positive? However after I scanned the second time, it was no longer infected. I used the same command to scan using RKhunter `sudo rkhunter -c` twice and found it weird that infected file is no longer infected

Answer (score 1):

Rootkit Hunter is not a virus scanner. It is an integrity checker. That is, it does not report a file as "infected", but as "modified".
This is an important difference because it explains why Rootkit Hunter may start or stop reporting a file.

If Rootkit Hunter stops reporting a file this may be simply because Rootkit Hunter's file properties database has been updated with the new properties of that file via `rkhunter --propupd`. Equally, if Rootkit Hunter starts reporting a file this may be simply because someone ran `apt-get upgrade` and there was a new version for it. Neither indicates directly that the file is or isn't infected.